# nested JSON value is an array, need to convert in string

Tags: json, typescript

I am using typescript, I have an JSON below

```
"product": {
        "prodId": ["PROD100"]// value in array
    },
    "packages": {
        "pkgId": ["PKG113"]// value in array
    }
```

the values are in array, my desired JSON should be like below

```
"product": {
        "prodId": "PROD100"
    },
    "packages": {
        "pkgId": "PKG113"
    }
```

Comment: Neither the input nor the output is valid JSON. Also, is this really JSON, or is it a javascript object?

Comment: @user9634982, you need to use JSON.stringfy() to convert object into JSON, on the other hand, to get it back , you should make use of JSON.parse(), and for the problem , refer to solution posted below by Darshil dave

Answer (score 2):

You can use toString method to convert Array into String

```js
const product = {
  "product": {
    "prodId": ["PROD100"] // value in array
  },
  "packages": {
    "pkgId": ["PKG113"] // value in array
  }
}
let newProduct = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product));
newProduct["product"]["prodId"] =  newProduct["product"]["prodId"].toString();
newProduct["packages"]["pkgId"] =  newProduct["packages"]["pkgId"].toString();
console.log(newProduct);
```